# Remove duplicated characters using regex

Tags: regex, matlab, parsing, string-parsing

How would you remove duplicated characters in regex while some characters are meant to be repeated?

For example, I have "BBAALLLLOOOONN" and I want the output to just be BALLOON.

I have tried this regex: /(.)(?=\1)/g but the result would be "BALON" instead of "BALLOON".

Comment: The only way is to have an English dictionary. Or are all the words always repeated? Because if that is the case, forget regexp. `A="BBAALLLLOOOONN"`; `A(1:2:end)`

Comment: Hi. All the characters (not words) are repeated in a .txt file I am reading from even punctuations and numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
regexprep(line, '([A-Za-z])\1', '$1')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/jAqBbM/1)

`()` is a capturing group referenced to with `\1`, `\1` consumes the duplicate char and only the captured letter is returned for each match as the replacement pattern is the `$1` backreference.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

don't use a lookahead. replace (.)\1 by \1.

In ruby that would be `"BBAALLLLOOOONN".gsub(/(.)\1/, '\1')`

Comment: The question is about MATLAB

Comment: OK, but this is about regular expressions, it can't be too difficult to adapt the ruby example to whatever.

Comment: While that's true, different languages support different regex features

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed. If anyone is curious, this is the equivalent logic in Matlab: regexprep(line, format, '$1') where line is a line of characters with duplicates such as BBAALLLLOOOONN!!, format is the regex which is '(.)\1' and '$1' equates to '\1'

Comment: HaiHey,  a lookahead does not 'consume' what it stands for. So in your version, you matched any character followed by the same character, but the second was not in the match.  The next global match hit that second character again if it was followed by the same character. This version consumes the second character, so the next global match starts after that second character.